# Promisify a function that creates a mongoose model instance (i.e. a document), saves it to the model, and returns then returns the model

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

I'm trying to Promisify the following function

```
let Definition = mongoose.model('Definition', mySchema)
let saveDefinition = (newDefinition) => {
  var newDef = new Definition(newDefinition);
  newDef.save();
  return Definition.find();
}
```

to achieve the following sequence of events

```
let saveDefinition = (newDefinition) => {
  return = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    // newDef = new Definition(newDefinition)
    // then
    // newDef.save()
    // then
    // return Definition.find()
  })
}
```

The goal is to invoke this function upon a request from the client, save a document to the model called "Definition" and return all of the documents within the model back to to the client. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not really sure on how to approach the problem

Comment: Nothing to [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) here - mongoose methods already do return promises, so [you should not use `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll stick with the original function

Comment: @Aditya That's not how promisification works.

Comment: @Tomalak, but I thought async await is a beautified way of writing promise based functions. Isn't it?

Comment: @Aditya Depends on your preferences. But a function that does nothing more than create a promise (e.g. via an API), and return it, gains nothing from an additional `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a function that creates a mongoose model instance (i.e. a document), saves it to the model, and returns then returns the model

There is nothing special you need to do. `.save()` already returns (a promise for) the saved document. Return it.

```
const Definition = mongoose.model('Definition', mySchema);

const saveDefinition = (data) => {
  const newDef = new Definition(data);
  return newDef.save();
};
```

Done.

---

I would write it differently to get rid of that global `Definition` variable:

```
const saveObject = modelName => {
  const Model = mongoose.model(modelName, mySchema);
  return (data) => new Model(data).save();
};

const saveDefinition = saveObject('Definition');
const saveWhatever = saveObject('Whatever');
```

---

Usage is the same in both cases

```
saveDefinition({ /* ... */ }).then(def => {
  // success
}).catch(err => {
  // failure
});
```

or

```
async () => {
  try {
    const def = await saveDefinition({ /* ... */ });
    // success
  } catch (err) {
    // failure
  }
};
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the global (module-scoped) `Definition`, the model will likely be used in multiple places

Comment: @Bergi No, not inherently - my `saveObject()` is in the same spot, after all. But wrapped into a factory like this, it's easier to re-use.